# Output of get_include_path() function

Tags: php

I'm getting this output when calling `get_include_path()` function.

> string(140)
>   "/var/www/companyname.eu/application../library:/var/www/companyname.eu/library/DomPdf:/var/www/companyname.eu/library:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear"

For me that path is a bit weird since it has semicolons and thing like `application../library:`

Can you explain me it?

Comment: Include path can use many folders, and : can be readed as OR.

Comment: Those are colons, not semicolons. A [path separator](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html).

Answer (score 2):

Multiple items are separated by colons, so you have these dirs in your path:

```
/var/www/companyname.eu/application../library
/var/www/companyname.eu/library/DomPdf
/var/www/companyname.eu/library
.
/usr/share/php
/usr/share/pear
```

The double dots refer to the parent directory, but you've likely got a typo here:

```
/var/www/companyname.eu/application../library
```

This probably should be:

```
/var/www/companyname.eu/application/../library
```

Which is the same as:

```
/var/www/companyname.eu/library
```

Which is already in the path on its own. So you can likely just drop that first entry without any issues.